# Customize Chrome based on location

Tags: google-chrome

I use Chrome at home and at work.  I need different bookmark availability and extensions enabled for each location.  Is there a way to do this without doing something like unsyncing my office computer from my google account and then changing it?  I suppose I could also create a separate google account for my work computer, but what I'd really like is for it just to recognize the IP or something along these lines and give me what I want.  I'm 99% sure it's not possible (other than what I suggested).